# Draggable and dropable boxes between different DIVs

Tags: html, jquery, css

I need some help here.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Organize Boxes</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .box {
      background-color: #f0f0f0;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 5px;
      text-align: center;
      cursor: move;
    }
    
    .group {
      margin: 10px;
      text-align: left;
      display: flex;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    
    .group1 {
      border: 1px solid blue;
    }
    
    .group2 {
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
    
    .group3 {
      border: 1px solid green;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class='boxes'>
    <div id="group1" class='group group1'>
      <div class="box" id="box11">Box 11</div>
      <div class="box" id="box12">Box 12</div>
    </div>
    <div id="group2" class='group group2'>
      <div class="box" id="box21">Box 21</div>
      <div class="box" id="box22">Box 22</div>
      <div class="box" id="box23">Box 23</div>
    </div>
    <div id="group3" class='group group3'>
      <div class="box" id="box31">Box 31</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I would like to organize de boxes (box XY) with drag-and-drop moving them between groups (.group). Observe that XY is the box position (row, column). There is no need rename them with new position.

It will be good if we have an effect when moving the boxes. Eg.: moving a box aside so that another can enter its position.

Thank you very much for your attention.

Comment: You have to try by yourself first, you can try with jQuery and jQuery UI : https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: yes! I have problems with efects...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic draggable/droppable demo with `helper: "clone"` that should do it.
There are two droppable elements: `box` (greedy) and `group` (not greedy) (see [droppable propagation](https://jqueryui.com/droppable/#propagation)).

The original draggable element is hidden while dragging.

```js
// make all box elements draggable
$(".box").draggable({
  helper: "clone",
  start: function(event, ui) {
    $(this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
  },
  drag: function(event, ui) {
    $(ui.helper).css('visibility', 'visible');
  },
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    $(this).css('visibility', 'visible');
  },
});

$(".box").droppable({
  accept: ".box",
  greedy: true,
  classes: {
    "ui-droppable-hover": "ui-state-hover"
  },
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    console.log(`Insert after ${$(this).attr('id')}`);
    $(ui.draggable).insertAfter($(this)).fadeIn('slow');
  },
});

$(".group").droppable({
  accept: ".box",
  greedy: false,
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    console.log(`Append to ${$(this).attr('id')}`);
    $(ui.draggable).appendTo($(this)).fadeIn('slow');
  },
});
```

```css
.box,
.dropped {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: move;
}

.group {
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 54px;
}

.group1 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.group2 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.group3 {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class='boxes'>
  <div id="group1" class='group group1'>
    <div class="box" id="box11">Box 11</div>
    <div class="box" id="box12">Box 12</div>
  </div>
  <div id="group2" class='group group2'>
    <div class="box" id="box21">Box 21</div>
    <div class="box" id="box22">Box 22</div>
    <div class="box" id="box23">Box 23</div>
  </div>
  <div id="group3" class='group group3'>
    <div class="box" id="box31">Box 31</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In this case, the boxes can dropped in any place from page...

Comment: This is better because doesn't show the box comming from ramdomic place...
But there is two things:
1 - After move a box, I can't move it again... and
2 - I'm still looking for the effect that moves one box away so I can put another one in its place.

Comment: And I also need a box to be able to fit between two others...

Comment: @WalterRobynson Please check the updated script.

Comment: It's getting better... It would be nice if the dragged box was hidden in its original position while moving...

Comment: Very good! Now I just need to be able to place a box between two others... And even better if before dropping it the other two move away... Like this **Grid Example** in [mdbootstrap](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/plugins/drag-and-drop/)

Comment: @WalterRobynson maybe post a new question on how to implement this specific feature and show your attempts...

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found was

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    $(".box").draggable({
        revert: true
    });

    $(".group").droppable({
        accept: '.box',
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).append($(ui.draggable));
        }
    });
});
```

But the efects isn't very good...

https://jsfiddle.net/bhqjg7p2/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).